# python Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'var'"

Tags: python, exception

im getting this exception in Python,

```
Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'population'" in del of <main.Robot instance at 0x104eb7098>> ignored
```

this is my code,

```
class Robot:

    population = 0 #class variable, number of robots

    def __init__(self, name):

        self.name = name
        print ('(initializing {0})'.format(self.name))

        Robot.population += 1

    def __del__(self):
        print('{0} is being destroyed!'.format(self.name))
        Robot.population -= 1

        if Robot.population == 0:
            print ('{0} was the last one.'.format(self.name))
        else:
            print('there are still {0:d} robots working.'.format(Robot.population))

    def sayHi(self):
        print('hole mi mestre me llama {0}'.format(self.name))

    def howMany():
        print('hay {0:d} robots'.format(Robot.population))
    howMany = staticmethod (howMany)


#instantiate 2 robots
mingos = Robot('alvergas')
mingos.sayHi()
Robot.howMany()

pingos = Robot('chupacabra')
pingos.sayHi()
Robot.howMany()

#destroy one
del mingos

Robot.howMany()
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your indentation is a mess. Please fix the syntax errors caused by bad indentation and I'll look again.

Comment: @Mako: I fixed the indentation in your example.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus, this has been the only thing that fixes so far my problem, if I create a method >>def delf(self):   this works, why doesnt like __del__ ?? thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I changed the code to run on Python 2.7 and added some prints, here's the result:

```
# So I changed the code as follows:

    class Robot:

        population = 0 #class variable, number of robots

        def __init__(self, name):

            self.name = name
            print '(initializing %s)' % self.name

            Robot.population += 1

        def __del__(self):
            print'%s is being destroyed!' % self.name
            print 'pre1 %s type %s' % (Robot, type(Robot))
            Robot.population -= 1

            print 'pre2'
            if Robot.population == 0:
                print '%s was the last one.' % self.name
            else:
                print 'there are still %d robots working.' % Robot.population

        def sayHi(self):
            print '%s says hi' % self.name

        def howMany():
            print 'there are %d robots' % Robot.population
        howMany = staticmethod(howMany)


    #instantiate 2 robots
    mingos = Robot('alvergas')
    mingos.sayHi()
    Robot.howMany()
    print 'end program'

# and the output is:

    (initializing alvergas)
    alvergas says hi
    there are 1 robots
    end prog
    alvergas is being destroyed!
    pre1 None type <type 'NoneType'>
    Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'population'" in
    <bound method Robot.__del__ of <__main__.Robot instance at 0x0223C918>> ignored
```

So the exception occurs after the program ends.
As [`__del__` description](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__) says: "when `__del__()` is invoked in response to a module being deleted (e.g., when execution of the program is done), other globals referenced by the `__del__()` method may already have been deleted or in the process of being torn down (e.g. the import machinery shutting down)."

I think that in your case the line `Robot.population -= 1` is called when the class Robot has already been torn down, becoming None. Trying to access an attribute of None causes an exception.

Comment: However, in this case `__del__()` should be called after the `del` statement: `del x doesn’t directly call x.__del__() — the former decrements the reference count for x by one, and the latter is only called when x‘s reference count reaches zero.`

Comment: `__del__()` shouldn't be called manually at all, it's called automatically `when x‘s reference count reaches zero`.

Comment: Yep, that's what I mean: right after the `del` statement, the `__del__()` method should be called **automatically**, as the OP expects. Maybe I've misused the verb "should", sorry.

Comment: Why don't we manage by ourselves the "garbages" before exiting the program ? I had the same problem and decided to destroy the instances with del() command in the code before exiting and the exception desappeared.
Well, that was not _real_ life, but just a lab ...

Answer (score 3):

I think I've found a "solution" for this

Just replace instantiate statements

```
#instantiate 2 robots
mingos = Robot('alvergas')
mingos.sayHi()
Robot.howMany()

pingos = Robot('chupacabra')
pingos.sayHi()
Robot.howMany()
```

with

```
#instantiate 2 robots
a = Robot('alvergas')
a.sayHi()
Robot.howMany()

b = Robot('chupacabra')
b.sayHi()
Robot.howMany()
```

Then it works!  Only changed the reference name to a & b!

So I'm a beginner of python, but I think @egor83 is right, when accessing Robot.population in the __del__ function while Robot has been torn down, error caused.

I guess changing the reference name to a & b may somehow influence the order that those objects been torn down. In this case, Robot may still exists when accessing Robot.population in __del__. So nothing seems went wrong.

Comment: Weird .. Can you elaborate more on how just changing the variable names work?

Answer (score 2):

This code (a re-indented version of your original code) works for me on Python 2.7.2:

```
class Robot:
    population = 0 #class variable, number of robots

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        print ('(initializing {0})'.format(self.name))
        Robot.population += 1

    def __del__(self):
        print('{0} is being destroyed!'.format(self.name))
        Robot.population -= 1

        if Robot.population == 0:
            print ('{0} was the last one.'.format(self.name))
        else:
            print('there are still {0:d} robots working.'.format(Robot.population))

    def sayHi(self):
        print('hole mi mestre me llama {0}'.format(self.name))

    def howMany():
        print('hay {0:d} robots'.format(Robot.population))
    howMany = staticmethod (howMany)


#instantiate 2 robots
mingos = Robot('alvergas')
mingos.sayHi()
Robot.howMany()

pingos = Robot('chupacabra')
pingos.sayHi()
Robot.howMany()

#destroy one
del mingos

Robot.howMany()
```

producing output:

```
(initializing alvergas)
hole mi mestre me llama alvergas
hay 1 robots
(initializing chupacabra)
hole mi mestre me llama chupacabra
hay 2 robots
alvergas is being destroyed!
there are still 1 robots working.
hay 1 robots
```

Remember Python has significant whitespace, so the indentation levels matter.